# Is it possible to determine if a type is a scoped enumeration type?

Tags: c++, enums, c++11, metaprogramming, type-traits

Is there a type trait, or is it possible to write a type trait `is_scoped_enum<T>` such that:

- if `T` is a scoped enumeration, `is_scoped_enum<T>::value` is `true` and
- if `T` is any other type, `is_scoped_enum<T>::value` is false

Comment: By *scoped enum*, you meant C++11's enum?

Comment: @Nawaz:  A scoped enum is what an `enum class` is called in C++11, yes.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what practical applications are there for this one?

Comment: @Xeo:  I am overloading the bitwise operators for a set of scoped enumeration types.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/wheels/src/353fc67489dc/include/wheels/enums.h%2B%2B

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Ha; that looks familiar.  :-) http://cxxreflect.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6963d00d7608#CxxReflect%2fFundamentalUtilities.hpp (search for `CXXREFLECT_GENERATE_SCOPED_ENUM_OPERATORS`)  Unfortunately, Visual C++ does not support `constexpr`, which makes scoped enums quite painful to use for flags, but at least with the operators it's _better_.  I like your traits usage, though. For flags, I've been using a `flags<T>` class type to wrap the enumeration.

Comment: With c++23 this will be in the standard.
If you can use c++17 or c++20 you can implement it in a shorter way than in R. Martinho Fernandes answer. cppreference has an example implementation for c++20:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_scoped_enum

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think testing if it is an enum *and* not implicitly convertible to the underlying type should do the trick.

```
template <typename T, bool B = std::is_enum<T>::value>
struct is_scoped_enum : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_scoped_enum<T, true>
: std::integral_constant<bool,
    !std::is_convertible<T, typename std::underlying_type<T>::type>::value> {};
```

Comment: Better use `std::underlying_type<T>` instead of `int`. An `enum class` in C++11 can base on something not convertible to `int`.

Comment: @KennyTM:  What type?  C++11 §7.2/2 states "The _enum-base_ shall name an integral type;" is there an integral type not convertible to `int`?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: You're correct. Sorry for confusion. (I was thinking of `is_convertible` doing implicit conversion.)

Comment: This is a good solution, except that with the latest edit, the logic is now backwards:  `::value` is true if `T` is an unscoped enumeration.  :-)

Comment: and one more correction, it should be !std::is_convertible<...>::value

Comment: I would like to add (because I've had this issue): This trait could also be implemented as one `using` statement (template alias) as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586163/c11-type-trait-to-differentiate-between-enum-class-and-regular-enum), but then `std::underlying_type` will be evaluated for all types, and some compilers generate an error when using `underlying_type` with non-enum types (no SFINAE). So this solution is probably the best one.

Comment: @Excelcius It's worse than the possibility of getting an error or not: using `std::underlying_type` with a non-enum type is undefined behaviour, which requires no diagnostic, so the compiler need not report the misuse, which then gives your program UB. I didn't look at common implementations but presume the Standard allows UB to facilitate easier implementation in valid use cases.

Answer (score 0):

C++23 will be providing *is_scoped_enum* which can be used once it gets implemented. See this link for documentation: [is_scoped_enum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_scoped_enum). I don't think clang supports this yet (see [clang status](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) for the latest info of what features are supported).

For now I am using a slightly simplified version of the answer above (using _v and _t) as well as an implementation of *is_underlying*:

```
// C++ 23 should include 'is_scoped_enum' and 'to_underlying' so the following
// code can be removed:

template<typename T, bool B = std::is_enum_v<T>>
struct is_scoped_enum : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_scoped_enum<T, true>
  : std::integral_constant<
      bool, !std::is_convertible_v<T, std::underlying_type_t<T>>> {};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_scoped_enum_v = is_scoped_enum<T>::value;

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_scoped_enum_v<T>, int> = 0>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto to_underlying(T x) noexcept {
  return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(x);
}
```