# std::is_enum<T> equivalent for identifying enum classes

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Consider this code:

```
enum CEnum {
    V1, V2;
};

enum class CppEnum {
    V1, V2;
};
```

Both `std::is_enum<CEnum>::value` and `std::is_enum<CppEnum>::value` is `true`.

I'm now searching for something like `std::is_enum_class<T>::value` to tell them apart.

Comment: likely duplicate of [C++11 type trait to differentiate between enum class and regular enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586163/c11-type-trait-to-differentiate-between-enum-class-and-regular-enum) or [How to implement is_enum_class type trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936640/how-to-implement-is-enum-class-type-trait)